# Loop iteration skip on timeout

Tags: bash, shell, timeout

So I have code something like this. There are two external scripts it runs and sometimes they run too long. I want to limit their execution adding timeout to each loop iteration, but I can't figure out how.

```
files=($pathgtp/*.*)

i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#files[*]} ]; do
  f=${files[$i]}
  o=$(basename -- "$f")
  o=${o%.*}
  o=$pathmid/$o.mid
  $PWD/GuitarProToMidi "$f" -o "$o" -f # first script here
  $pythonvenv $pythonscript "$o" # second script here
  rm "$o" # remove temporary file
  ((i++))
done
```

Comment: why use a `while` loop with an integer iterator to emulate a `for` loop when you can just iterate over the values in the `files` array?  e.g.  `for f in "${files[@]}"; do ... ; done`.   Also, you need to be more consistent in double-quoting your variables - your script will break if $pythonenv, $pythonscript, or the current working directory ($PWD) contain any spaces.

Comment: I chose to use `while` cause in some cases I need to start loop from specific `$files` array element. And thank you with `$pythonenv $pythonscript`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `timeout` from GNU `coreutils`.  From `man timeout`:

> **NAME**
>
> `timeout` - run a command with a time limit
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>  timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
>  timeout [OPTION]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Start `COMMAND`, and kill it if still running after `DURATION`.
>
> [...]